# Xamarin Forms- Entry, Picker etc losing its values after resuming app from background or unlocking phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin Forms app & came across an issue where my form fields like Entry, Picker etc losing its values after resuming app from background or unlocking phone post screen timeout.
I am using conventional winforms approach in my codebehind. I am not using MVVM Pattern.
Please help me..

Environment is
Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.6.2 with all latest packages of Xamarin Forms or Essentials etc.

### Update {{CODE}}

Below is my code to set data to form fields.

```
 private void FillUser()
        {
            var userid = PersistentObjects.UserId;
            var user = new UserController().GetUserProfileById(userid);
            if (user != null)
            {
                TxtAadhar.Text = user.AadharNumber;
                TxtAchievements.Text = user.Achievements;


                DdlArtField.SelectedItem = ((IList<MasterItem>)DdlArtField.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == user.ArtDomain);
                DdlLanguages.SelectedItem = ((IList<MasterItem>)DdlLanguages.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == user.ArtLanguage);


                DdlProfession.SelectedItem = ((IList<MasterItem>)DdlProfession.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == user.ArtProfession);
                DdlEducation.SelectedItem = ((IList<MasterItem>)DdlEducation.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == user.QualificationId);
                TxtMobileNum.Text = user.MobileNumber;
                TxtBankAccount.Text = user.BankAccount;
                DdlBanks.SelectedItem = ((IList<MasterItem>)DdlBanks.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == user.BankId);
                DdlBloodGroups.SelectedItem = user.BloodGroup;//((IList<MasterItem>)DdlBloodGroups.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == user.BloodGroup);
                TxtExp.Text = user.DomainExperience.ToString();
                TxtFathersName.Text = user.FathersName;
                TxtEmail.Text = user.Email.ToLower();
                DdlGender.SelectedItem = user.Gender;
                TxtFullName.Text = user.FullName.ToTitleCase();
                TxtIfscCode.Text = user.IfscCode.ToUpper();
                TxtDob.Date = user.Dob;
                TxtAltMobile.Text = user.AltMobileNumber;
                TxtLocality.Text = user.Locality.ToTitleCase();
                DdlDistricts.SelectedItem = ((IList<MasterItem>)DdlDistricts.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == user.DistrictId);
                TxtPO.Text = user.PostOffice.ToTitleCase();
                TxtVillage.Text = user.VillageName.ToTitleCase();
                TxtThana.Text = user.PoliceStation.ToTitleCase();
            }
        }
```

### APP.Xaml.cs

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OneSignal.Current.SetLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
            OneSignal.Current.StartInit(Constants.OSAppId).HandleNotificationOpened(NotificationOpenClicked).InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification).EndInit();
            Application.Current.MainPage = new Login();

        }

        private void NotificationOpenClicked(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
        {
            PersistentObjects.ClickedNotification = true;

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            OneSignal.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();
        }



    }
```

The form fields , having  values , coming from database and is displaying in the form fields are working as expected. The form fields that are blank and needs user input are getting refreshed or emptied.
I hope this will help.

If you need code of special area/operation please do let me know.

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show us the relevant code?

Comment: @Jason, OP is asking how to retain values on the form when activity is suspended (even killed) and resumed.

Comment: Generally, form values should not be cleared if the app remains in memory.  That's why I'm asking for code.

Comment: very hard to answer without code, but one thing to be aware of is that onappearing will fire when the app returns to the foreground, so don't reset values in that every time.

Comment: @BenReierson - I hope, I have my answers now.. I have FillUser() in OnAppearing(), seems like causing reset..

Comment: Check the states of your device. You could save the data when you resuming app from background or unlocking phone. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BenReierson Comment helped me. It was a nasty mistake...I was calling api and filling data to form fields using FillUser() method, which is glued in OnAppearing().
Removing that from there worked!!!!

Thanks.